# Rooting LG e400f

Tags: rom-flashing, rom

I'm trying to root my Lg optimus e400f With GingerBreak, So far I haven't heard of any successes is it possible ? any help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: Did you try **Methods/apps** in the guide [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/96277)?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions:

1. Download the **Key root Master MOD**. I uploaded it to my Google Website [here](https://sites.google.com/site/matthewswebpage1999/android). Scroll down to the bottom of the page and download the "Install.apk
2. Sideload the APK
3. Click the second button **Mulai Root** and a popup will show
4. Click the button that says **root** and another popup will show button in purple with 2 buttons (one red and one purple)
5. Click the **purple** button
6. Your phone should be rooted and have [SuperSU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) installed
7. Optional: Use a [root checker](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=root+checker) to check if you actually have root privileges

This was the only root method that worked for me, as all the other ones didn't work.

You may see [Stop Looking And Root Phone Here!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3quOOMmZ2qk) video. I didn't use this video for my guide but this shows you how to use the app (as the app shows interface in Chinese language).